# Get only text that included in div, without text in other tags in this div

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I have html, like this:

```
<div id = "foo">
  I want to parse this!
  <ul class = "contact-data">
    <li> Don't need</li
    <li> heyyay </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My ruby code:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
page.css('div.foo')
```

And `page.css('div.foo').text` return all text in this `div` with text in `ul` tags.

What is the best way to take text that I needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to get the first match of the *CSS rule*, use [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css)

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-HTML
<div id = "foo">
  I want to parse this!
  <ul class = "contact-data">
    <li> Don\'t need</li
    <li> heyyay </li>
  </ul>
</div>
HTML

@doc.at_css("div#foo > text()").text.strip # => "I want to parse this!"
```

**update**

When you want to get all the matches of the *CSS rule*, use [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css)

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-HTML
<div id = "foo">
  I want to parse this! - I
  <ul class = "contact-data">
    <li> not need</li
    <li> heyyay </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id = "foo">
  I want to parse this! - II
  <ul class = "contact-data">
    <li> not need</li
    <li> heyyay </li>
  </ul>
</div>
HTML

@doc.css("div#foo > text()").each do |elm|
  puts elm.text.strip
end
# >> I want to parse this! - I
# >> I want to parse this! - II
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, it's work. But this method works only for one div on page, and I want to parse text from some div's with `id = "foo"` on the page.

Comment: @IgorBiryukov Yes.. for multiple div you need to use `#css` method, and for only one element you need to use `#at_css` method.. Let me update my answer with some example..